# The title and default values ​go together

Tags: react-hooks, material-ui, react-tsx

In react useForm hook title and default values ​​go together
how can I fix is?

[image]

I want it like in this image:

[image]

It is a my MUI component

```
 <Controller
                    name="description"
                    control={control}
                    rules={{ required: 'description is required' }}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...field}
                            type="text"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            label="description"
                            error={Boolean(errors.description)}
                            helperText={(errors.description?.message) || ''}
                        />
                    )}
                />
```

I tried this but it's not what I want

```
 <InputLabel htmlFor="title">Title</InputLabel>

                <Controller
                    name="title"
                    control={control}
                    rules={{ required: 'title is required' }}
                    render={({ field }) => (
                        <TextField
                            {...field}
                            type="text"
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            error={Boolean(errors.title)}
                            helperText={(errors.title?.message) || ''}
                        />
                    )}
                />
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can review your code in context and help sort it out.